# Transcations in SQL CE on WP7

Tags: transactions, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1

Sometimes when working on a WP7 app i see SQLCEException which states that some table doesn't exist. I suppose that DB gets corrupted because app is being closed when im writing to DB (doing SubmitChanges() on dedicated thread).

The question is - Does mango database support transactions and should it recover on next startup somehow when it sees that some write query didn't finish successfully and if not can I somehow do that manually?

Comment: Why not include a ready database in your app installer?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed any form of attempted recovery on startup.  Typically if the SQL CE database faults, and you don't have catch on the load, you're app will just crash.  I'm running into similar problems on my SQL CE DB app.  I've found that the most reliable method for stability is to attempt large DB mods as a background task.  That way if the user closes the app for whatever reason the DB write doesnt fault the DB.